# Android listview data doesn't persist when re-created

Tags: java, android

I have a listview that uses a custom arrayadapter that loads a layout with text + a radiobutton. The user should only be able to select a single item in the list at a time - so basically only one radio button should be 'checked' at any time. This works perfectly except when the activity is recreated, like when the screen is rotated. I can't figure out why it's doing this, so maybe you all can think of something?

Here's the code for the activity that has the listview:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class TimeForm extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private MyArrayAdapter maa;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_form);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);

        String listitems[] = new String[16];

        listitems[0] = "Other";

        for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
        {
            listitems[i] = "Job " + i;
        }

        maa = new MyArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_list, listitems);

        if(savedInstanceState != null)
            maa.selIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("selIndex");

        lv.setAdapter(maa);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        EditText et = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        if(position == 0)
        {
            et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if(maa.selItem != null)
        {
            RadioButton rOld = (RadioButton) maa.selItem.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            rOld.setChecked(false);
        }

        RadioButton r = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        r.setChecked(true);

        maa.selIndex = position;
        maa.selItem = view;
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b)
    {
        b.putInt("selIndex", maa.selIndex);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_time_form, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Code for MyArrayAdapter class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private String[] strings;
    private int layoutID;

    public int selIndex;
    public View selItem;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context c, int id, String[] values)
    {
        super(c, id, values);

        selIndex = -1;
        selItem = null;

        this.strings = values;
        this.context = c;
        layoutID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rView = inflater.inflate(layoutID, parent, false);

        TextView tv = (TextView) rView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(strings[position]);

        if(position == selIndex)
        {
            RadioButton r = (RadioButton) rView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            r.setChecked(true);
            selItem = rView;
        }


        return rView;
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can the user select multiple entries, or is the previously selected entry no longer visible? Please clarify.

Comment: ^ I'm assuming that the radio button doesn't stay checked...

Comment: No, the radio button stays checked. However, say i check the 2nd radio button, then rotate the screen. Then i check the 3rd radio button. The 2nd one stays checked when i check the 3rd one - that's my problem. If i scroll the list so the checked items are out of view then scroll back to it, only the 3rd one is checked and not the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm not sure it's the best possible solution, but it works and doesn't cause any noticeable performance loss. ^_^

In the TimeForm activity's onItemClick() method, i added this at the bottom:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.invalidateViews();
```

This forces the listview to redraw all the child views. Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing's first, with regards to 're-creating' the view.. check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html.

You can define `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` to ensure that your activity isn't recreated on rotation, for example.

That said, if you want to persist the values, you'll have to actually do that, and then apply any selections to your collection passed into your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: I wrote code to persist the values, and it's not working like i expect it to. View my comment on my question to get a better idea of what it's doing.

Comment: I see.. I believe you should be able to take care of this issue by triggering `maa.notifyDataSetChanged();` on the array adapter or invalidate the listview: `lv.invalidate();` **after** setting the radio checked. Note: You'll want to run this on the UI thread.

Comment: I had tried invalidating the listview to get it to redraw the child views, but it didn't work. I have, however, found a solution.

Comment: curious -- did you trigger the data set changed method? either way, curious to know what you ended up doing. btw, in your view, you're setting checked to true, but there's no else condition where you set it to false...

Comment: I found an API that specifically redraws the views in the listview. Thanks for pointing that out. I think the radio buttons default to unchecked, but it doesn't hurt to specify it.